# Usuarios diferentes con mismo mail y pocos minutos de diferencia

Tags: soporte, usuarios-no-registrados

Este es un usuario que hizo una pregunta sin registrarse y quedó como fantasma:

- https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/75742/mario

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es **"otro"** usuario que **1 minuto después** usó el mismo nombre, usó la misma dirección de mail (porque tienen [el mismo identicon](https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/hash/)), y publicó una respuesta a esa pregunta (que debería haber sido edición).

- https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/75743/mario

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Teniendo en cuenta que no es ni la primera ni la última vez que veo un caso así, ¿alguien me puede explicar cómo es que el sistema los toma como usuarios diferentes y no como el mismo? ¿o qué pasos hay que hacer para reproducirlo?

Comment: Te ha faltado un tercero con el que hizo una edición a la pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/75744/mario

Comment: No lo había visto.. Pero ahí usó una dirección de mail diferente, por lo que no me extraña que lo tome como 2 usuarios diferentes. Me preocupa estos dos, con mismo mail, y supongo que mismo IP y misma PC por tener 1 minuto de diferencia.

Comment: posible bug? deberiamos preguntas en meta SE?

Comment: @gbianchi Si fuese un bug, necesitaría poder reproducirlo antes de reportarlo... Pero sobre todo, es lo mismo que hablé con fedorqui sobre un tema de Transifex: [en algún punto (probablemente ingenuo), me gusta seguir pensando en la idea de que MSOes es un sitio funcional, donde los problemas como estos son identificados y son elevados por los caminos que tienen que ir hasta llegar a los devs, y que no es necesario que un usuario tenga que "salirse" de SOes para arreglarlo](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42893167#42893167)... y sigue.

Comment: Interesante cuestión. Y la de veces que un usuario luego sugiere una edición a su propia publicación, pero ya con otra cuenta...